# javascript style is only applied to element if using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, settimeout

I have a working solution on snippet below and also on [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/rikkarv/rodqahs7/)

However I don't like it because it only works if using setTimeout with interval value equal to zero or plus.

It should work without having to use setTimeout, it's the same logic than setting interval to zero.

Does anyone knows why it doesn't work without the setTimeout?

```js
const PACE = 4;
const CONTAINER = document.getElementById('container');
const ANCHOR = document.getElementById('anchor');
const ENTRIES = [{
    'url': '#1',
    'text': 'news nº 1'
  },
  {
    'url': '#2',
    'text': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua'
  },
  {
    'url': '#3',
    'text': 'news nº 3'
  },
  {
    'url': '#4',
    'text': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua'
  }
];
let counter = 0;

function getDuration() {
    return ((ANCHOR.getBoundingClientRect().width + CONTAINER.getBoundingClientRect().width) / CONTAINER.getBoundingClientRect().width) * PACE;
}

function moveAnchor() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    ANCHOR.style.transitionDuration = getDuration() + 's';
    ANCHOR.style.left = (-1 * ANCHOR.getBoundingClientRect().width) + 'px';
  }, 0);
  // I want to replace the above code with:
  //ANCHOR.style.transitionDuration = getDuration() + 's';
  //ANCHOR.style.left = (-1 * ANCHOR.getBoundingClientRect().width) + 'px';
}

ANCHOR.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
  counter++;
  if (counter === ENTRIES.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }
  ANCHOR.href = ENTRIES[counter].url;
  ANCHOR.innerHTML = ENTRIES[counter].text;
  ANCHOR.style.transitionDuration = '0s';
  ANCHOR.style.left = CONTAINER.getBoundingClientRect().width + 'px';
  moveAnchor()
});

moveAnchor();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background: firebrick;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#anchor {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  transition-property: left;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <a id="anchor" href="#1" target="_blank">news nº 1</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Setting a 0 length timeout moves the code to the next execution cycle, however in this case I'm not sure what the problem is, removing the timeout doesn't seem to affect the functionality for me?

Comment: Just a heads up that you could potentially use pure CSS for this. see https://codepen.io/kupuguy/pen/GNopye

Comment: @DBS that is something weird too, because if you remove it does not affect but in an initial setup without the timeout it affects (it is hard to explain this)

Comment: @Squiggs. that is a great solution and I am going to look to this in detail. However the point here is that I am more looking to understand this setTimeout behavior/issue instead of searching a solution

Comment: The @DBS comment it is a plus because it points me to the "execution cycle" which can be a interesting topic to explore. Thank you both for your help and mentoring